# Having two identical ids in different xml files

Tags: android, xml

Can I assign the same id name to two different views which are in two different xml files?
It won't let me change it using "Edit ID.." button, but when I change it manually, it doesn't say anything and works fine. But might it become a problem and why?
If possible, please add a link or an general explanation on android visual tree build, I would really like to learn on the subject.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to have the same ID in multiple XML files. The only time this might be a problem is if you had a nested layout containing an ID which is also present in the parent.

Having the same ID can actually be useful in some cases- for example if you load a different XML file in different circumstances (such as portrait and landscape) you can give views the same ID, so in code you just call findViewById once and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same ids in same layout ..  but if their behavior is different then it is possible.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


Button btn;
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.btn1);

}
```

You can use the same ids in different layouts but it is recommended that you use different ids for different layouts because when you will deal with lots of layouts then it will create a problem to recognize which id is for which layout  ...